# how to use AsyncValidator interface for forms in angular 4.0.0 rc.1

Tags: angular

Angular 4.0.0 rc.1 released on 24 February,2017
There are two changes for forms 
forms: **added option to use browser's native validation and angular forms** 
forms: **introduce AsyncValidator interface**
How to use AsyncValidator interface for forms  and how can we enabled browser's native validation?

Answer (score 0):

You would use it the same way you would a regular `Validator`. The only difference is that instead of returning a `ValidationErrors` object, you return a Promise or Observable which resolves to the `ValidatorErrors` object.

Here is an example:

```js
this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
  email: ['', [ Validators.required ]]
});
```

This is a simple signup form with required fields.  Now lets say you want to call your server to make sure the email isn't already in use.

duplicate-email.ts

```js
export class DuplicateEmail {
  constructor(private backendService: BackendService) {}

  validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> {
    return this.backendService.isDuplicateEmail(c.value)
      .map(response => response ? { duplicateEmail: true } : null);
  }
}
```

form.component.ts

```js
this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', [ Validators.required ]],
  email: ['', [ Validators.required ], [ duplicateEmail ]]
});
```

Congrats, you have now implemented an async validator!